# Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{...}: java.lang.InstantiationException

Tags: android, apk

I've tried all the solution of all threads I've read.
Any suggestion?

I've debugged the application but the exception is in the internal code od android and there's no number of line.

This is the class

```
package com.beppe.reminder;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ReminderShow extends Activity{

private Context mCtx; 
private long ID;
private DBAdapter db;
private Cursor c;



ReminderShow(Context c){
    mCtx=c;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    db=new DBAdapter(mCtx);
    setContentView(R.layout.reminder_show);


    TextView tit=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.title11);
    TextView bod=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.body11);
    TextView dat=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.date11);
    TextView tim=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.time11);
    if(getIntent()!=null){
        ID=getIntent().getExtras().getLong(DBAdapter.KEY_ROWID);
        db.open();
        c=db.fetchTaskById((int)ID);
        c.moveToFirst();
        tit.setText(c.getString(1));
        bod.setText(c.getString(2));
        dat.setText(c.getString(3).split(" ")[0]);
        tim.setText(c.getString(3).split(" ")[1]);
    }
}
}
```

and this is the manifest

The activity is declared correctly and if I delete it from the package the compiler shows me an error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.beppe.reminder"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="10" />
<permission android:protectionLevel="normal" android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"></permission>
<permission android:protectionLevel="normal" android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"></permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.beppe.reminder.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity 
        android:name="com.beppe.reminder.TaskEdit"
        android:label="@string/edit_label"></activity>
    <activity 
        android:name="com.beppe.reminder.ReminderShow"
        android:label="@string/show_label"></activity>
</application>
```

here is the logcat

```
enter code here03-05 15:36:33.474: W/dalvikvm(22257): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d560)
03-05 15:36:33.484: E/AndroidRuntime(22257): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-05 15:36:33.484: E/AndroidRuntime(22257): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to    instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.beppe.reminder/com.beppe.reminder.ReminderShow}: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.beppe.reminder.ReminderShow
03-05 15:36:33.484: E/AndroidRuntime(22257):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1573)
03-05 15:36:33.484: E/AndroidRuntime(22257):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
03-05 15:36:33.484: E/AndroidRuntime(22257):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
03-05 15:36:33.484: E/AndroidRuntime(22257):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
03-05 15:36:33.484: E/AndroidRuntime(22257):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-05 15:36:33.484: E/AndroidRuntime(22257):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
03-05 15:36:33.484: E/AndroidRuntime(22257):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
03-05 15:36:33.484: E/AndroidRuntime(22257):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-05 15:36:33.484: E/AndroidRuntime(22257):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-05 15:36:33.484: E/AndroidRuntime(22257):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
03-05 15:36:33.484: E/AndroidRuntime(22257):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
03-05 15:36:33.484: E/AndroidRuntime(22257):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-05 15:36:33.484: E/AndroidRuntime(22257): Caused by:  java.lang.InstantiationException: com.beppe.reminder.ReminderShow
 03-05 15:36:33.484: E/AndroidRuntime(22257):   at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
03-05 15:36:33.484: E/AndroidRuntime(22257):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1409)
03-05 15:36:33.484: E/AndroidRuntime(22257):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
03-05 15:36:33.484: E/AndroidRuntime(22257):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1565)
 03-05 15:36:33.484: E/AndroidRuntime(22257):   ... 11 more
```

Comment: Is there no _caused by_ in the exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove constructor which you have used to initiate the context of activity as you will easily get your context here by `ReminderShow.this`:

Right Now you are passing null context here at line `db=new DBAdapter(mCtx);`

Remove Constructor :

```
ReminderShow(Context c){
    mCtx=c;
}
```

and Change this :

```
 db=new DBAdapter(mCtx);
```

to

```
db=new DBAdapter(ReminderShow.this);
```

Comment: this solved the problem. Can you tell me why the constructor caused the problem?

Answer (score 1):

because you are passing null `mCtx` to `DBAdapter` class. change your code as :

```
public class ReminderShow extends Activity{

        private Context mCtx; 
        private long ID;
        private DBAdapter db;
        private Cursor c;


        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.reminder_show);
            db=new DBAdapter(ReminderShow.this);
             // your code here....
```